# How do we add a text in React table pagination component?

Tags: reactjs, pagination, react-table

basically i need to  add another text at the end . ie. , Page 1 of 2 recordds

[image]

I tried this property nextText={"nextpage"}, but does not work,Thoughts ?

Comment: Means after `2` you want to add `records`?

Comment: something like that , yes,  i added 'Page' using pageText={'Page'}

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ofText` prop

```
ofText= 'of records'
```

Which will give you ouput like,

```
Page 1 of records 2
```

Comment: i tried ofText, but i need the text after the number, eg: Page 1 of 2 records,

Comment: Ideally it should be `Page 1 of 2 pages`, because `2` is the number of pages, correct? And standard is `Page 1 of 2` this only. Adding extra text doesn't make sense.